# ssh via putty using hostname in opensuse

Tags: linux, dns, dhcp

I am using opensuse 11.3 and it is connected to DHCP network. I am using putty to connect top machine from window with command:
putty -ssh user@ip-address (it works fine)
but when trying to connect using hostname it fails to resolve:
putty -ssh user@

Every time I want to connect to machine i need to check its ip first and then connect via putty, but when want to connect using hostname it fails and says not able to resolve. Is there a way around so that i can use a common hostname for Linux machine without worrying about its IP address which changes after every reboot?
Thanks for reply.

Regards,
Ashutosh

Comment: take a look at your /etc/resolve.conf .. it's possible that your DHCP server is not generating a 'search domain.com' .. and you'll have to time user@hostname.domainname to connect ...

Comment: I recommend migrating this question to Server Fault, where you're more likely to get the right answer. Can you ping the Debian host from your Windows box? Are you using a short hostname or a fully-qualified domain name.

Comment: im using opensuse 11.3 system, i don't know its debian or not. It is office pc so i cant ping the name but its like <hostname>.<system-type>.<credentials>.<company-name>.com and alias is <hostname>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions to this problem (ordered by increasing difficulty order).

1. Change the opensuse server interface configuration so that it takes a static address instead of relying on the DHCP server.
2. DHCP reserved IP address. If you also run the DHCP server, the make sure the MAC address of the opensuse adapter is always assigned the same IP address.  If you're on you domestic LAN at home, then this is probably done on the Internet router.  Use the http interface and navigate to the DHCP server configuration form.

   In the first two cases, then you just need to update your windows host files in \windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts to assign a name to that static address.
3. Configure the opensuse machine to update the DNS/WINS database upon being assigned a DHCP address.
4. Use a common fixed address server to synchronise a configuration file upon change of network status/address.  Develop a sync client service on windows to automatically update the host file upon reception of the notification.

Comment: hi, i tried with another machine with static ip and edited /etc/hosts with ip address at line where hostname is written, but still im not able to connect via hostname. Is there is something extra i have to do?

Comment: im sorry for my silly work if any on linux, since im very new to linux